# plot bar graph with column names on x axis

Tags: python

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMWEv.png) how to plot a bar graph using python with column names on x axis and the total of the first column on y axis. I have a dataframe similar to this

```
     Name  1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 
  0   A      10    2   15   20   18
  1   B      13   14   18   11   17
  2   C      12   17    8   10   13
  3   D       9   15   16    6    9
  4   E      19   18   13   17   19
  5   Total  63   66   70   64   76
```

I want to plot a bar graph with x-axis = 1990,1991,1992,1993,1994 and y-axis = Total values. Any help with python code would be much appreciated.

could anyone help me with the dynamic scatter plot using plotly express taking years 1990, 1991,1992,1993,1994 on x-axis and corresponding yearly data on y-axis. The Name column values to be taken as animation. as the play button is clicked, the data corresponding to the year and name value should move from 1990 to 1994

Comment: pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar should be able to give you what you need as long as your dataframe is organised properly. The x-axis will be the one labelled "Name", so df.plot.bar(x='Name', y='Total', rot=0) should work.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
my_list=list(df.columns)
del my_list[0]
years = my_list
totals = df.sum()
ax.bar(years,totals)
plt.show()
```

but you have to delete the last line in your data frame

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
#  sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    '1990': [5, 6, 7, 9, 2],
    '1992': [15, 2, 7, 5, 11],
    '1994': [2, -6, 21, 6, 2]},
    index= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

)

# Transposing the dataframe before plotting
df.T.plot()
```

[image: Using cols in X-axis and Index as Y-axis]

Read more about Pandas Dataframe Plot fns, its really powerful!

```
df.T.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sampath.  But I already have a dataframe with 10 columns and 10 rows and I need a bar graph.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. This is the full solution

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
namesofxaxis= ['C', 'C++', 'Java', 'Python', 'PHP']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'Total'},
     '1990': {0: 10, 1: 13, 2: 12, 3: 9, 4: 19, 5: 63},
     '1991': {0: 2, 1: 14, 2: 17, 3: 15, 4: 18, 5: 66},
     '1992': {0: 15, 1: 18, 2: 8, 3: 16, 4: 13, 5: 70},
     '1993': {0: 20, 1: 11, 2: 10, 3: 6, 4: 17, 5: 64},
     '1994': {0: 18, 1: 17, 2: 13, 3: 9, 4: 19, 5: 76}})
     
print(df)
print('\n')
res_df  = df.iloc[5:,1:]

print('\n')
res_df1  = df.iloc[3:3,:]
namesofxaxis=list(df.columns[1:])
print((res_df.values.tolist()))
flat_ls = [item for sublist in res_df.values.tolist() for item in sublist]
print('\n')

print('\n')
print((namesofxaxis))

Mine_std = [2, 3, 4, 1,5]

width = 0.3
  
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  
ax.bar(namesofxaxis,flat_ls, width, 
       yerr = Mine_std, 
       label ='Mine')
  

ax.set_ylabel('Articles')
ax.legend()
  
ax.set_title('matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar Example')
  
plt.show()
```

Comment: where is `df` defined?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to just plot the 'Total' row by year. You can use pandas plot, first filter the dataframe down to just the total line then `set_index` and transpose, `T`, the dataframe rows and columns, then use `pd.DataFrame.plot`:

```
df.query('Name == "Total"').set_index('Name').T.plot()
```

Output:

[image]

For bar chart:

```
df.query('Name == "Total"').set_index('Name').T.plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

A minimum complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E', 5: 'Total'},
 '1990': {0: 10, 1: 13, 2: 12, 3: 9, 4: 19, 5: 63},
 '1991': {0: 2, 1: 14, 2: 17, 3: 15, 4: 18, 5: 66},
 '1992': {0: 15, 1: 18, 2: 8, 3: 16, 4: 13, 5: 70},
 '1993': {0: 20, 1: 11, 2: 10, 3: 6, 4: 17, 5: 64},
 '1994': {0: 18, 1: 17, 2: 13, 3: 9, 4: 19, 5: 76}})

df.query('Name == "Total"').set_index('Name').T.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Scott.  Any help with bar graph please

Comment: I am a newbie to python. Could you please help me with the complete code so that I can incorporate it with my dataframe

Comment: I am getting error "None of ['Industry'] are in the columns". Name = Industry in my dataframe

Comment: Okay, you don't have a row with 'Industry' or you are dealing with 'whitespace' issues.  Not in this small test dataframe, I have a row with 'Total'.  the error you are getting is with the 'set_index' method.

Comment: What would be the other option without set_index method.

Comment: I got the bar graph by removing the set_index method.  But I need to increase the size of the graph. Could you please help me

Comment: Use figsize=(10,8) in side bar.   "....T.plot.bar(figsize=(10,8))"  See docs on [pandas visualization](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html)

Comment: Scott could you please help me with the dynamic scatter plot using plotly express taking years 1990, 1991,1992,1993,1994 on x-axis and corresponding yearly data on y-axis. The Name column values to be taken as animation.  as the play button is clicked, the data corresponding to the year and name value should move from 1990 to 1994